# uiscrollview is NOT bouncing to the top

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I don't understand why this is happening. If I drag the app to the BOTTOM of the page and release, it bounces up.. but not all the way to the top..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 750)];
}
```

Comment: Is your contentSize correct? 750 is higher then the screen (480).

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an indicator that your scroll view's `contentSize` property is being set to less than is actually required to show everything on screen. Adjust `contentSize.y` to a higher value than 750 to see if this solves the problem.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I changed the contentSize.y to 1000 and it allows me to scroll further DOWN.  It still BOUNCES somewhat... but it does not bounce all the way to the top of the APP.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. The .y needed to be changed to 480! Thank you DrummerB

    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];